# Check if month is greater than today's month

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 7.1.8` and I would like to check if the given month is greater than today's month:

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
<?php

$releaseDate =  date('m/d/Y', strtotime("01/11/2018")); // November, 1st 2018

echo date("m/Y") . "\n \n";
if($releaseDate <= date("d/Y")) {
    echo "Today is SMALLER than : " . $releaseDate;
} else {
    echo "Today is GREATER than : " . $releaseDate;
}

echo "\n";
```

For example, for the date `01/11/2018` it should be `GREATER` than today and `27/06/2018` it should be `SMALLER` than today.

I am guessing that I do not parse the date correctly with `'m/d/Y'`.

Any suggestions from your side what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that u entered invalid format here:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime("01/11/2018")) // November, 1st 2018
```

Because of u are using DAY/MONTH/YEAR it should be:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime("01/11/2018")) // November, 1st 2018
```

Better description of format that you can find here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php